# PySpark put data to https

Tags: api, https, pyspark, put

I have a spark dataframe (PySpark) with data for 250,000 customer. Now I want send this data to an HTTPS API (as a JSON file). 
The actual solution is to use the Python requests package to send the data, which is working fine for a small set of data. But for that, I have to collect all data on one node and send it from there.

Is there a better solution for this use case?
Can I run a function on each node to store the data to the https api?

Many thanks
Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the dataframe to rdd then call the foreachPartition or foreach

```
def f(iterator):
    for x in iterator:
        #Implement the api call here
        print(x)

df.rdd.foreachPartition(f)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Do you have any idea how I can implement the API call in Spark (PySpark)?